# Nifi: Create a Kafka topic with PublishKafka with a specific number of partitions/replication-factor

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I am using Apache Nifi version **1.10.0**. I have put some data into Kafka from Nifi using the `PublishKafka_2_0` processor. I have three Kafka brokers running along side with Kafka. I am getting the data from Nifi but the topic that is created in Nifi have a replication-factor of 1 and partitions of 1.

How can I change the default value of replication-factor and partitions when creating a new topic in PublishKafka? In other words, I want the processor to create new topics with `partitions=3` and `replication-factors=3` instead of 1.
I understand that this can be changed after the topic is created but I would like it to be done dynamically at creation.

Comment: changing default value in kafka conf is not enough ?

Comment: @maximeG that worked! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your setup correctly, you are relying on the client side for topic creation, i.e. topics are created when NiFi attempts to produce/consume/fetch metadata for a non-existent topic. In this scenario, Kafka will use `num.partitions` and `default.replication.factor` settings for a new topic that are defined in broker config. (Kafka defaults to 1 for both.) Currently, updating these values in `server.properties` is the only way to control auto-created topics' configuration.

[KIP-487](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-487%3A+Client-side+Automatic+Topic+Creation+on+Producer) is being worked on to allow producers to control topic creation (as opposed to being server-side,  one-for-all verdict), but even in that implementation there is no plan for a client to control number of partitions or replication factor.

Comment: The workaround would be a one-time shell action in Nifi to run `kafka-topics.sh --create`